# PHP script to output an HTML form to txt file?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to create a PHP file that will write the text from an HTML form to a txt file, and then redirect the user to a page that tells them they're finished.

**Here is my HTMl form:**

```
<form action="feedbackScript.php">
 <p>
   Email(for response, optional) 
    <input type="email" name="email" /> <br>
   General feedback and comments
    <textarea name="feedback" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea> <br>
   Rating <br>
    <select name="rating">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
   Suggestions
    <textarea name="suggestions" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea> <br>
   Bug Report
    <textarea name="bugReport" cols="100" rows="5">(Fill out this form)
     What happened: 
     What you expected to happen: 
     Anything extra: </textarea> <br> <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
 </p>
</form>
```

How can this be done?

EDIT: Was originally going to use this:

```
<?php

// Open the text file
$f = fopen("feedbacks.txt", "w");

// Write text
fwrite($f, $_POST['email'] && $_POST['feedback'] && $_POST['suggestions'] && $_POST['bugReport']); 

// Close the text file
fclose($f);

header('Location: suggestFinished.html'.$newURL);

?>
```

Sorry for misleading title, another question I was going to post was still here and I forgot to edit the title

Comment: Can you post your PHP code also?

Comment: Ok, well The Alpha's answer below is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The question was at first: "No post data to process"

Use `method='POST'` in your form like:

```
<form action="feedbackScript.php" method="POST">
```

By default, it uses `GET` request if you don't use any request method.

### Update after the `edit`

You have this:

```
fwrite($f, $_POST['email'] && $_POST['feedback'] && $_POST['suggestions'] && $_POST['bugReport']);
```

This won't work because you need to pass a string, for example, something like this:

```
$string = implode(',', $_POST) . "\n"; // me@ymaiol.com,some feedback text,...,...
fwrite($f, $string);
```

So, it doesn't matter how you format the string (using comma or other way) but it must be a `String`.
[Check the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It does to a certain extent, but OP wants to know how to write to file, no? However, that may very well be the answer, but OP's PHP isn't showing, which is why I rather not put in an answer.

Comment: Well, the title says `HTML form and PHP 'no post data to process'` so I thought (and method is missing) this is the problem but if `OP` needs anything else then I may answer the specific question.

Comment: +1 You're entirely right on that. I usually like to see OP's PHP when it comes to questions like these, just to be safe ;) Edit: OP changed the question's title. OP had code in a comment but now deleted it which did contain `$_POST` variables. It's now in the question.

Comment: Anonymous Down voter, please explain, also the title/question has been changed/updated.

Comment: Those downvoters hardly ever say the reason. Stack should really change that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending a form with a get method (default method) you can access to a users data by $_GET global array. Just open a file and use json_encode method to insert into file encoded string of user data (you can decode it later using json_decode method)

```
<?php

    $file = fopen('/tmp/user_request.txt');
    fwrite($file, json_encode($_GET));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you don't know what the heck you are doing; even your HTML code and form are so bad. Having said that, I'll try to help.

```
<?php
/**
 * feedbackScript.php
 * This file writes to .txt file the contents of an HTML form.
 */

// All the values of the HTML form are securely stored in the array $v:
$v = array_map('trim', filter_input_array(INPUT_POST));

// Format your text however you want before it's written to .txt file:
$text = '-- START ' . date('c') . ' --\n'
    . "User email:{$v['email']}\n" 
    . "Feedback and Comments:\n"
    . "{$v['feedback']}\n\n"
    . "Rating: {$v['rating']}\n"
    . "Suggestions: {$v['suggestions']}\n"
    . "Bug Report: {$v['bugReport']}";

// Following lines of code open, write, and close your connection
// to a text file:
$handle = 'path/to/your/txtfile.txt';
$fp = fopen($handle, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $text);
fclose($fp);
```

PS: Fix your HTML before you even jump into the PHP. And why is this question posted under jquery? Also, make sure your method is POST in your form, i.e. method="POST"

Comment: *"Obviously you don't know what the heck you are doing; even your HTML code and form are so bad."* It's condescending.

Comment: I made sure I had a solid foundation of HTML & CSS before I jumped into PHP. It just seems some people are way over their head trying things all over the place without any structure. I want to learn C++ and Java, which I know nothing about, but before that I want to learn PHP even some more. People need discipline, especially in computer science. Anyway, I helped the guy out didn't I? Cut me some slack! lol